# Blogger OAuth API - How to automatically post to Google+?

Tags: oauth, google-plus, blogger

Google announced the "automatically post to Google+" feature a few days ago for Blogger posts. (It shares blog posts automatically to a Google+ profile or page) Is that feature available for posts through the API or just from the Blogger web interface? It seems that it's only working from the interface, but maybe I'm missing a scope or parameter?

Scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/"
```

PHP cURL for posting:

```
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'blogger#post',
    'blog' => array('id' => $blogID),
    'title' => $postTitle,
    'content' => $postMessage
);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blogID.'/posts/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an official answer, but I would note that scheduled posts also do not get auto-posted to Google+. It only does the post at the time of an explicit client action (ie - making the blog post).